# pscp files to aws with proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-proxy, pscp

Need to pscp java war file to aws. however, we are not able to do as connection needs a proxy and there is no option to pass proxy along with pscp command. we tried explicitly setting http_proxy on the cmd. still, it didn't work. Has anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I get around it by using the `-load` option to load the putty configuration where I placed the proxy.

Example:
`pscp -load "my aws" test.txt 172.93.184.11:/work/`